# get source code for method with @property decorator python

Tags: python, introspection, inspect

Suppose I have a class MyClass that has a property created with the @property decorator, like this:

```
class MyClass(object):
    @property
    def foo(self):
        if whatever:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Suppose I want to use the python inspect module to get the source code that defines the property. I know how to do this for methods (inspect.getsource) but I don't know how to do this for property objects. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Huh. I'm surprised `inspect.getsource` doesn't handle that automatically.

Comment: It might be worth requesting that as a new feature

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Access the underlying getter function through the property's `fget` attribute:

```
print(inspect.getsource(MyClass.foo.fget))
```

If it has a setter or deleter, you can access those through `fset` and `fdel`:

```
print(inspect.getsource(MyClass.foo.fset))
print(inspect.getsource(MyClass.foo.fdel))
```

Comment: awesome! Just what I needed!